# Sending ajax form, several time

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

There is my  code in following: (Yii framework)

View form: `view.php`

```
<div class="form">
<?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
        'id'=>'user-profile',
        'action' => 'index.php?r=upanel/user/update',
        'method' => 'post',
    ));
?>
    <?php $form->errorSummary($model) ?>
     . . .
     . . .
     . . .
     . . .
     . . .
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php
            $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/update');
            echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Update Profile',$url,array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'data'=> "js:$('#user-profile').serialize()",//var data = $('#user-form').serialize();
                'datatype'=>'html',
                'success'=>'callback',
                'error'=>'error',
            ));
        ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget() ?>
</div> <!-- End CActiveForm-->

<p><?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success') ?></p>

<script>
function callback(data,status){
    if (status=='success')
            $('#user-profile').html(data);
}

function error(jqXHR, textStatus , errorThrown){
    console.log(jqXHR);
    $('#error').html('callback error');
}
</script>
```

actionUpdate in controller: `actionUpdate()`

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $model=$this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $model->scenario = 'updateProfile';

    if(isset($_POST['User'])){
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->validate()){
            if ($model->save()){
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Successfully Updated');
                    $this->renderPartial('view',array('model'=>$model));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is: when the form is sent first time, `print_r($_REQUEST)`show the data form been sent(in post method), but after that `view.php` rendered with `partialrender()` in `actionUpdate`, `print_r($_REQUEST)` show there is no data in the sent form to the server despite the form is filled. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just only a clumsy mistake.

In callback function on `success` i should have updated `div` HTML element instead `form`.

Changing from:

```
function callback(data,status){
    if (status=='success'){
            $('#user-profile').html(data);
    }
```

To:

```
function callback(data,status){
    if (status=='success'){
            $('#user-profile-div').html(data);
    }
```

Thanks friends for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Please Take care these points when handling ajax button,link in Yii.

1.when using CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton or CHtml::AjaxLink use `'live'=>false` and should have an unique id:

```
array('id'=>'uniqueId', 'live'=>false)
```

2.If it is an AJAX request, Use

```
$this->renderPartial('_view', array(
                   'model'=>  $model,
               ), false, true);
```

3.if it is a normal request Use

```
$this->renderPartial('_view', array(
                   'model'=>  $model,
           ), false, false);
```

4.Assign to your ajax link or button a random ID

```
CHtml::ajaxLink('send a message', '/message', 
    array('replace' => '#message-div'), 
    array('id' => 'send-link-'.uniqid())
);
```

[Useful Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/178/how-to-avoid-multiple-ajax-request/)

Comment: I do those, but hadn't effect. I am trying to debug program, but will wait for the guidance friends.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to stop the form being regenerated and updation on previos state:

```
$this->renderPartial('view',array('model'=>$model),false,true);
```

Note the `false,true` added in renderPartial method.